# Evaluating Recommendation status

Tags: peer-review

For a submitted paper, what does the status "Evaluating Recommendation" mean and how long does it last?

Comment: Give some more context. Recommendations for what?

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt about an aspect of paper submission ask the journal editor or conference committee. Only they can give you information as to how long the review process may take, and they can also let you know what the submission status terms mean for the particular journal/conference that you have applied to.